# K&R 2nd Edition, Example 1.9 Character Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have a question in regards to the getline() function and parameter definition in the following code.  The code is taken directly from K&R chapter 1.9: "Character arrays".  I have reproduced it here verbatim.  The issue is that when I compile the program as is I get three errors,(which I have reproduced at the end).  When I change the function, and the function parameter definition to get_line() (with an underscore instead of just getline) in the three places where I get the errors, the errors stop and the program runs as expected.

My question is:

### What has changed in C, so that getline() is not valid, but get_line() is a valid name for a function definition?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000    // maximum input line size

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */

int main()
{
    int len;            //current line lenght
    int max;            //maximum length seen so far
    char line[MAXLINE]; //current input line
    char longest[MAXLINE];//longest line saved here

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
        if (max > 0)   //there was a line
            printf("%s", longest);
            return 0;
}

/*  getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c !='\n'; ++i) 
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
        s[i] = '\0';
        return i;
}


/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[],char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

The errors I get are:

- ./section 1.9.1.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline';
  `int getline(int line[], int maxline);`
- ./section 1.9.1.c:17:40: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
  `while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0);` and
- ./section 1.9.1.c:30:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
  `int getline(int s[], int lim)`

Comment: This is not an answer, just a general comment on K&R: don't use the practices advocated in that book.

Comment: Cannot chat now; just brief 2 cents why you shouldn't start with K&R for two reasons. 1: K&R advocate practices that were popular 30 years ago before people grew to understand that such practices often lead to buggy code and always lead to poorly maintainable code. There are plenty more recent books on C. 2: if your objective is objective-C, then you should start with a book on objective-C: even if the features of C are retain, the mode of thinking how to program may differ enough between the languages, and you shouldn't contaminate one with the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stdio library distributed with `glibc` declares a function that is also called `getline` with a different signature than yours. Since you cannot declare two functions with the same name the compiler gives an error. The conflicting declaration of `getline` found in stdio.h is:

```
   ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

The `getline` function was originally a glibc extension, and has then been included in POSIX.1-2008. **It is not a standard C function.**

If you are using `gcc` you can get standards-compliant behavior by using the `-std` command line switch. Among other things this hides declarations of non-standard functions. Try for example:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 "section 1.9.1.c" -o "section 1.9.1"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was wondering what the notes were apart from the errors I was getting: `/usr/include/stdio.h:449:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAI...`

Comment: Depends on what is meant by "standard", `getline` is defined in "a" standard, just not in any of the official C language standards... The point is, if you want to write standard C using `gcc` you can use the `-std` command line switch.

Comment: The standards compliant gcc suggestion does not work, I still get the same errors. However I now fully understand what is going on here:`/usr/include/stdio.h:449:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAI...` Thanks again, extremely helpful.

Comment: Using `-std=c11` (or `-std=c99`, or `-ansi`) will definitely work.

Comment: Sir, Should I Read K&R Second Edition Or Not , I am confused in this regard as there are changes in Language , I Want to have a advice on this matter, Can You Help ?

Answer (score 3):

`stdio.h` already has a declaration of [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html),

You should not use same name to define your `getline` function.

If you want to declare and define same function, you should use another name. like `get_line()`

Answer (score 2):

You get a conflict between your new-declared getline function and the one declared in stdio.h.