# Why do I get this error: Conflicting types for getline

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Can somebody please take a look at this and tell me what is wrong. I have 3 errors:

1. `error: Conflicting types for getline`
2. `error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3 have 2`
3. `error: conflicting types for getline`.

I'm sure I have overlooked something simple but I cannot find my error. Thank you, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline); /* conflicting types for getline */
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

main() {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];
    
    max = 0;
    
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) /* too few arguments to call, expected 3 have 2 */
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;          
            copy(longest, line);
        }   
    
    if (max > 0)
        //printf("longest line = %d characters\n -->", max);
        printf("%s", longest);

    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim) { /*conflicting types for getline*/

    int c, i;
    
    for(i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {

    int i;
    i = 0;
    
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: The name is colliding with library function.

Comment: As the 'Related' sidebar over there points out: his question ends up being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763052/why-do-i-get-a-conflicting-types-for-getline-error-when-compiling-the-longest and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338600/kr-2nd-edition-example-1-9-character-arrays .

Comment: @SteveSummit Ah you're right! I didn't find those when searching around before asking this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's GNU function [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) with the same, which is not part of C standard.
Presumably, you are compiling with no `-std` (a specific C standard) specified that makes exposes this function's GNU declaration from `<stdio.h>`.

You could compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` like:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 gl.c
```

or rename your function to something like `my_getline()` to avoid this conflict.

Also, `main()`'s signature needs to be one of the standard ones. Since, you don't use commandline arguments, you can use:

```
int main(void) { .. }
```

See: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 8):

The easy answer: don't call your function `getline`.  That name's been taken.

(I know, it's an example in K&R.  So you ought to be able to use it, right?  Unfortunately, no.  Bugs me, too.)

The slightly longer answer: there's now a semistandard `getline` function, which yours conflicts with.  You're getting the same kind of errors you'd get if, say, you tried to name one of your own functions `printf`.  There may be a way to say, "I don't want to use the standard `getline` function, I want to use my own", but in this case, it's probably not worth it.

(On a personal note: I've been programming in C for about 35 years, and for about 34.9 of those years I've been using my own `getline` function, ever since I read about it in K&R.  But over the past year or so I've been having to rewrite all of my programs, to call my own function `fgetline` instead of `getline`, to get around this problem.)

Comment: Thank you very much. P.P answered first but your information very helpful to me as well

Comment: But `fgetline` sounds like it's getting from file ?

Comment: @artm I used that name because my function (unlike K&R's) reads from an explicitly-specified `FILE *`.

Comment: `getline` is very much standard, POSIX 2008.

Comment: I really want to know now how, but especially *why*, you used your own getline?

Comment: @forgetfulfunctor Two reasons: (1) K&R taught me how to, and it seemed like a good idea at the time, and (2) I find my own (f)getline is generally handier than the standard `fgets` because it (a) doesn't put the `\n` in the returned buffer, (b) returns a count instead of a pointer, and (c) discards characters that won't fit, rather than leaving them on the input stream.